# iOS - CATransition and transitionWithView issues

Tags: ios, transition, catransition

Whenever I use either `CATransition` or `transitionWithView` to "push" one view from the right, there is a brief moment where the view that's getting pushed in fades in from black (or whatever the background color is), and the view that's getting pushed away fades out to black.

This might be the intended effect, but it looks messy on my app, and was wondering if anyone knows of a way to prevent this "fade out/in" effect?

Here is the CATransition code I am using to present the new view:

```
myView = [[MyView alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyView" bundle:nil];
[myView setDelegate:self];

[[mainView layer] addAnimation:pushRightTransition forKey:nil];

// Add the view:
[mainView addSubview:[myView view]];
```